# How to edit a section of a file using FS?

Tags: javascript, fs

I'm trying to use fs to rewrite a variable in another file without changing/deleting other variables, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I want to edit a file named data.json that has a lot of variables in it. Something like:

```
"b": {
    "ra": 100,
    "error": 0
}
"a": {
    "ra": 100,
    "error": 0
}
```

How do I edit B without deleting A?

Right now I have this code:

```js
var datajson = fs.readFileSync(`data.json`);
var data = JSON.parse(datajson);

startdata = {
    b: {
        ra: 0,
        error: 1
    }
}

fs.writeFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify (startdata, null, 4), err => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

The problem with this code is that it deletes every other line of code from data.json and I end up with this:

```
"b": {
    "ra": 0,
    "error": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` will rewrite the whole file.

What we can do about it, we have to write existing content as well. You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (or object spread) to merge objects:

```
var newdata = Object.assign({},data,startdata)
```

The above line of code will...

- Create a new object
- Assign properties of `data` and `startdata` to that object (properties of `startdata` will overwrite the properties of `data`)
- Save the result to `newdata`

So, your code should look like this:

```js
var datajson = fs.readFileSync(`data.json`);
var data = JSON.parse(datajson);

startdata = {
    b: {
        ra: 0,
        error: 1
    }
}

var newdata = Object.assign({},data,startdata)

fs.writeFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify (newdata, null, 4), err => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `spread` operator

```
startdata = {
    ...data,
    b: {
        ra: 0,
        error: 1
    }
}
```

Spread operator syntax on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax).

Make sure to validate your JSON as well:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

## nodejs fs has a [createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) method.

its **options** lets you set the **start** pointer/ offset of the file.
write the new buffer then close the stream and you should be fine.

the math is just to estimate the start position - that is a readers exercise ;)

in your example it should be just

```
// untested!
let index = fs.readFileSync('data.json') // "b" ...
            .indexOf("b") // 2
if(index == -1) throw;
const ws = fs.createWriteStream(`data.json`, {start: index, flags: "rs+"});
ws.on('error', errHandler(err));
ws.on('close', function continueFromHere(){})
ws./*write*/end(JSON.stringify (startdata, null, 4), (err)=>notGuaranteedErrHandler(err));
```

Comment: But what if the new data is longer/shorter than the old data?

Comment: @FZs i guess you will not have any memory issues running readFile, writeFile - but in the future once you got more comfortable try to remember "there are streams" ;)